# rsyslog failing on boot -- unable to start service no matter what

Tags: boot, rsyslog

RSYSLOG started failing on one of my servers a week ago and i'm having a hard time troubleshooting it without any logs :) Rsyslog fails on boot of a Centos 5 system and im unable to start it manually. There is plenty of space in /var/log and on the system itself. If I try to start manually with service rsyslog start, it takes forever to try to start but will eventually fail. I've rebooted in to runlevel 1 and tried to start manually, but get the same results.

Im having issues looking for way to resolve this as a lot of recommendations instantly go to space on the system. Please let me know if you guys have any ideas on what I can check.

Thanks in advance for your consideration! (im sure someone will edit my post and remove this section because appreciation is not part of the problem or whatever... but, I am thankful for your time. So, thanks.)

Comment: CentOS 5, released in 2007, is [End Of Life](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#head-fe8a0be91ee3e7dea812e8694491e1dde5b75e6d) and rather than trying to debug this issue you might want invest your time in an upgrade instead. - Having said that: use `strake` to see where exactly the delay originates from.

Comment: Did yum try to reinstall syslogd and break rsyslog? Do you have any telemetry from the most recent successful log? Are all other services running normally? Have you audited rsyslog.conf to see if there's anything in there you aren't expecting? I'm assuming there are no specific error messages when trying to start it manually?

Comment: Thanks -- this server doesn't have too much life on it so I just need to keep it alive for another 2 months. I saw someone mention strake on a site, but I can't find a ton of info on it. I just found the github so ill look at it. thanks.

Comment: Don't show a yum updates near the time when things stopped working. I do have visibility to the last good logs though. It shows network connections failing and then it basically stops. I did have /var/log mounted to an NFS share but that has moved. If I just had it mount that folder to the share, would that cause it to break if its no longer there? Right now /var/log is properly mounted to the sda2. It can store files and im able to read all the logs up until Apr26.   I dont see anything weird with rsyslog.conf but maybe im missing something? The server is not used often.No errors on man start

Comment: Sorry that is a typo and should be [`strace`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)

Comment: If moving the nfs share broke it, I would check the configuration and ensure that you have updated all relevant lines to the new location. If it was just a symlink and you have updated the symlink you shouldn't have any issues there. Do you still have the packages for syslogd (default install if memory serves) and does that run correctly?

Comment: I'll check back through the configuration and make sure that everything is where it should be. I thought that rsyslogd replaced syslogd -- would I even need to worry about syslogd? It shouldn't be linked since it was just mounted but ill check for any symlinks that are trying to point to the old NFS.  Thank you.

Comment: very nice -- strace is showing a lot of information and this is a command I was not familiar with. I'll see if I can get some information off of rsyslog with this.

Comment: If you had added rsyslog without removing the packages for syslogd I figured that might let you test alternative log sources. If you removed them in the process obviously that doesn't help much.